# Change mouse cursor in jgraphx

Tags: java, jgraphx

How can I change the mouse cursor in mxGraphComponent in jgraphx?

I managed to change the default cursor (when it's not over any vertex or edge) by overriding mxGraphHandler.getCursor:

```
new mxGraphHandler(graphComponent) {
        @Override
        protected Cursor getCursor(MouseEvent e) {
            return mxGraphHandler.FOLD_CURSOR;
        }
};
```

But the cursor still changes when it's over vertex or edge. I found some hint on closed forum: http://forum.jgraph.com/questions/3883/change-mouse-cursor-based-on-vertex-mouse-is-over , but there is no getCursor(MouseEvent) method in mxGraphHandler, so I guess it's outdated or related only to JS version.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your mouse override method-

```
graphComponent.getGraphControl().setCursor(FOLD_CURSOR);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. It's the same effect as only returning cursor. So still over the edges and vertices cursor changes, which I don't want.